# Number of functions $f:\{1,...,n\}\to\{1,...,n\}$ that have $|f^{-1}(\{i\})|=i$ for some $i$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, inclusion-exclusion

Let $S=\{1,...,n\}$, I am looking at number of functions functions $f:S\to S$ such that there exists $i \in S$ such that $$|f^{-1}(\{i\})|=i$$

I am guessing I am supposed to use [PIE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) (Principle of Inclusion and Exclusion)

I let $X=\{f:S\to S\}$.
My attempt is to define $A_i=\{f\in X;|f^{-1}(\{i\})|=i\}$.

It can be computed that $|A_i|=\binom{n}{i}(n-1)^{n-i}$.

Similarly, $|A_i\cap A_j|=\binom{n}{i}\binom{n-i}{j}(n-2)^{n-i-j}$.

but I am not sure how to proceed.

Comment: why don't you know how to proceed? don't you just get ${n \choose i_1}{n-i_1 \choose i_2}\dots{n-i_1-\dots-i_{k-1} \choose i_k}(n-k)^{n-i_1-\dots-i_k}$ for $i_1+\dots+i_k \le n$?

Comment: i know it has this form, but this is almost useless, i am wondering if there is a nicer and easier way to calculate this

Comment: can you give the values for the first few $n$

Comment: @mathworker21: The first few values are $(1,3,16,147,1\,756,\ldots)$. The sequence is not archived in OEIS.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $a_n, n\geq 1$ denote the number of functions $f:[n]\to[n]$ such that there exists $i\in [n]$ such that
\begin{align*}
|f^{-1}(\{i\})|=i
\end{align*}

Calculation of $a_n$ for small numbers $n$ gives
\begin{align*}
(a_n)_{n\geq 1}=(1,3,16,147,1\,756,\ldots)
\end{align*}
which is archived in OEIS as *[A331538](https://oeis.org/A331538)* (thanks to @MarkoRiedel).

**General expression:**

Using PIE we can write
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{a_n}&=\sum_{j=1}^n\left|A_j\right|-\sum_{{1\leq j_1<j_2\leq n}\atop{j_1+j_2\leq n}}\left|A_{j_1}\cap A_{j_2}\right|\\
&\qquad+\cdots+(-1)^{k-1}\sum_{{1\leq j_1< j_2<\ldots<j_k\leq   n}\atop{j_1+j_2+\cdots+j_k\leq  n}}\left|A_{j_1}\cap   A_{j_2}\cap    \cdots\cap A_{j_k}\right|\pm\cdots\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^n\binom{n}{j}(n-1)^{n-j}-\sum_{{1\leq j_1<j_2\leq n}\atop{j_1+j_2\leq n}}\binom{n}{j_1,j_2,n-j_1-j_2}(n-2)^{n-j_1-j_2}\\
&\quad+\cdots+(-1)^{k-1}\sum_{{1\leq j_1<\ldots<j_k\leq   n}\atop{j_1+\cdots+j_k\leq  n}}\binom{n}{j_1,\ldots,j_k,n-j_1-\cdots-j_k}(n-k)^{n-j_1-\cdots -j_k}\pm\cdots\\
\end{align*}

Here  we  use the  multinomial coefficient notation $\binom{n}{j_1,\ldots,j_k}=\frac{n!}{j_1!\cdots  j_k!}$.

> **Main  term:**
>
> The   following is valid for $n\geq1$
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{j=1}^n\left|A_j\right|=n^n-(n-1)^n\tag{1}
> \end{align*}
>
> [Simplification thanks to @darijgrinberg]: We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{j=1}^n\left|A_j\right|}&=\sum_{j=1}^n\binom{n}{j}(n-1)^{n-j}\\
> &=\sum_{j=1}^n\binom{n}{j}1^j(n-1)^{n-j}\\
> &=(1+(n-1))^n-(n-1)^n\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=n^n-(n-1)^n}
> \end{align*}
>   and the claim (1) follows.

**Note:** The sequence $\left(\sum_{j=1}^n\left|A_j\right|\right)_{n\geq 1}=(1, 3, 19, 175, 2\,101,\ldots)$ of the main terms is archived in OEIS as *[A045531](https://oeis.org/A045531)*.

Comment: Can't you save yourself (3)--(6) by using the binomial theorem?

Comment: @darijgrinberg: Answer revised and simplified. Thanks again for pointing at it.

Comment: You don't need those denominators either :) Just pair that lonely $\left(n-1\right)^{n-j}$ with an invisible $1^j$.

Comment: @darijgrinberg: Thanks again darij. This time with citation.

Comment: @MarkusScheuer It seems to me this sequence should have a place in the OEIS.

Comment: @MarkoRiedel: I fully agree.

Comment: @Nasal: Many thanks for accepting my answer and granting the bounty.

Comment: @MarkusScheuer There is a user at this [MSE link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3543013/) who requires an introduction to coefficient extractors and formal power series. Could you maybe help here?

Comment: @MarkoRiedel: I see you already provide helpful hints. (+1)

Answer (score 6):

Using combinatorial classes as in *Analytic Combinatorics* by Flajolet
and Sedgewick we  get for the complementary problem  i.e. no pre-image
$f^{-1}(k)$ of $k$ having $k$ elements the class

$$\def\textsc#1{\dosc#1\csod}
\def\dosc#1#2\csod{{\rm #1{\small #2}}}
\prod_{k=1}^n \textsc{SET}_{\ne k}(\mathcal{Z})$$

with EGF

$$F(z) = \prod_{k=1}^n  \left(\exp(z)-\frac{z^k}{k!}\right).$$

The desired quantity is then given by

$$n^n - n! [z^n] F(z)$$

or

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
n^n - n! [z^n]
\prod_{k=1}^n  \left(\exp(z)-\frac{z^k}{k!}\right).}$$

It appears that for computational purposes the alternate form below
is slightly more efficient:

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
n^n - n! [z^n]
\prod_{k=1}^n  \sum_{q=0, q\ne k}^n \frac{z^q}{q!}.}$$

Here we have used the class

$$\def\textsc#1{\dosc#1\csod}
\def\dosc#1#2\csod{{\rm #1{\small #2}}}
\prod_{k=1}^n \textsc{SET}_{\ne k, \le n}(\mathcal{Z}).$$

The sequence starts as follows:

$$1, 3, 16, 147, 1756, 25910, 453594, 9184091, 211075288, 5427652794,
\\ 154380255250, 4812088559014, 163110595450466, 5973198636395003,
\ldots $$

Comment: Instructive answer. (+1)

Comment: Thank you and thanks also for the credit. I can submit to the OEIS or should we wait for a few more days? Or do you want to submit yourself?

Comment: I don't expect additional information. So, it would be fine for me if you could add this sequence to the archive.

Comment: Done: [OEIS A331537](https://oeis.org/A331537) and [OEIS A331538](https://oeis.org/A331538).

Comment: Many thanks for archiving the sequences. Very nice new entries. :-)

Comment: You're welcome. We have MSE to thank.