# prove $ \sum_{m=0}^{n-k} {n-m-1\choose n-k-m} \\ = [z^{n-k}] (1+z)^{n-1} \sum_{m=0}^{n-k} z^m (1+z)^{-m} $

Tags: binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

How it can be show that:

> $$ \sum_{m=0}^{n-k} {n-m-1\choose n-k-m}
> \\ = [z^{n-k}] (1+z)^{n-1} \sum_{m=0}^{n-k} z^m (1+z)^{-m}  $$

I tried to use binomial theorem, but since the upper limit does not mach to $n-m-1$ in the binomial coefficient then I could not continue.
If you want to prove that please start with the left hand side

Comment: What does $[z^k]$ mean here?

Comment: @AlecB-G,we use the coefficient of operator $[t^p]$ to denote the coefficient of $t^p$ in a series

Comment: This problem appeared at the following [MSE link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3543013/).

Answer (score 1):

Start from right hand side
\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\sum_{m=0}^{n-k}z^m(1+z)^{n-m-1}&=\sum_{m=0}^{n-k}\sum_{\ell=0}^{n-m-1}z^{m+\ell}\begin{pmatrix}n-m-1\\\ell\end{pmatrix}\\
\end{aligned}\end{equation}
So we see the coefficient of $z^{n-k}$ is at $\ell=n-k-m$, and the result follows.

Comment: well I actually want to start from the LHS, since we don't know where does the RHS come from.

Answer (score 1):

What I intended to do at the linked post was this:

$$\sum_{m=0}^{n-k} {n-m-1\choose n-k-m}
\\ = \sum_{m=0}^{n-k} [z^{n-k-m}] (1+z)^{n-m-1}
\\ = \sum_{m=0}^{n-k} [z^{n-k}] z^m (1+z)^{n-m-1}
\\ = [z^{n-k}] \sum_{m=0}^{n-k}  z^m (1+z)^{n-m-1}
\\ = [z^{n-k}] (1+z)^{n-1} \sum_{m=0}^{n-k}  z^m (1+z)^{-m}.$$

When $f(z) = \cdots + z^{n-k-m} f_{n-k-m} + \cdots$ then 
$z^m f(z) = \cdots + z^{n-k} f_{n-k-m} + \cdots$ and therefore
$f_{n-k-m} = [z^{n-k-m}] f(z) = [z^{n-k}] z^m f(z).$

Answer (score 0):

Let $n=p+k$, multiply by $z^p$, and sum to compute the generating function:
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{p=0}^\infty\sum_{m=0}^p\binom{p+k-1-m}{p-m}z^p
&=\sum_{m=0}^\infty\sum_{p=m}^\infty\binom{p+k-1-m}{p-m}z^p\tag1\\
&=\sum_{m=0}^\infty\sum_{p=m}^\infty(-1)^{p-m}\binom{-k}{p-m}z^p\tag2\\
&=\sum_{m=0}^\infty z^m\sum_{p=0}^\infty(-1)^p\binom{-k}pz^p\tag3\\
&=\sum_{m=0}^\infty\frac{z^m}{(1-z)^k}\tag4\\
&=\frac1{(1-z)^{k+1}}\tag5
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(1)$: change order of summation
$(2)$: apply [negative binomial coefficients](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/217647)
$(3)$: substitute $p\mapsto p+m$
$(4)$: sum in $p$
$(5)$: sum in $m$

Now use the generating function
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{m=0}^{n-k}\binom{n-1-m}{n-k-m}
&=\left[z^{n-k}\right]\frac1{(1-z)^{k+1}}\tag6\\
&=(-1)^{n-k}\binom{-k-1}{n-k}\tag7\\
&=\binom{n}{n-k}\tag8\\[6pt]
&=\left[z^{n-k}\right](1+z)^n\tag9\\[6pt]
&=\left[z^{n-k}\right](1+z)^{n-1}\frac1{1-\frac{z}{1+z}}\tag{10}\\
&=\left[z^{n-k}\right](1+z)^{n-1}\sum_{m=0}^\infty\frac{z^m}{(1+z)^m}\tag{11}\\
&=\left[z^{n-k}\right](1+z)^{n-1}\sum_{m=0}^{n-k}\frac{z^m}{(1+z)^m}\tag{12}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\phantom{1}(6)$: apply $(5)$; i.e. pull out the $p=n-k$ coefficient
$\phantom{1}(7)$: apply the Binomial Theorem
$\phantom{1}(8)$: apply negative binomial coefficients
$\phantom{1}(9)$: apply the Binomial Theorem
$(10)$: $1+z=\left(1-\frac{z}{1+z}\right)^{-1}$
$(11)$: apply the power series for $(1-x)^{-1}$
$(12)$: discard terms with powers of $z$ higher than $n-k$

Comment: ,can you please first change the order of summatiom and then apply negative binomial theorem?the only part I cannot understand is part $(2)$,I don't know how did you change the order of summation.

Comment: For $(1)$: negative binomial coefficient: $\binom{p+k-1-m}{p-m}=(-1)^{p-m}\binom{-k}{p-m}$ and for change of order of summation: note that the sum is over all $p\ge m\ge0$. For $(2)$: everywhere you see a $p$, write $p+m$.

Comment: so you are saying that $$\sum_{p=0}^{\infty}\sum_{m=0}^{p}{\binom{p+k-1-m}{p-m}}z^{p}=\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\sum_{p=m}^{\infty}{\binom{p+k-1-m}{p-m}}z^{p}$$?

Comment: Yes, that is the change of order of summation.

Comment: @user715522: I have expanded the explanation to hopefully be clearer.

Comment: ,In part $2)$ how do you know for $\binom{p+k-1-m}{p-m}$ you need to use negative binomial theorem?

Comment: It gets rid of the $p-m$ in the upper part so that we can apply the binomial theorem to sum in $p$ in step $(4)$.

Comment: So $p+k-1-m$ is not negative and you did it just because you wanted to use that in step $4$?

Comment: Yes.${}{}{}{}{}$